# program data randomizes only when run with break point

Tags: database, jsp, caching, random, breakpoints

i have a program that generates a 2 question test from an SQL DB by question and by answers, the questions are selected randomly by a question id. the problem I'm having is when run normally from net beans the the questions don't randomize in fact on a new system that hasn't run before it doesn't show any questions. but when it is debugged with break points it works perfectly fine. i had something like this happen to another program a while ago and not sure how i fixed it, i believe it was an issue between caching and the math Random.

welcome page load to the quizzical controller which on init generates a test in TestDA servlet

```
package org.citatscc.quiz.controller;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.citatscc.quiz.business.*;
import org.citatscc.quiz.business.TestTaker;
import org.citatscc.quiz.data.TestDA;


public class Quizzical extends HttpServlet {
    //the test will be available to all threads
    //eventually each TestTaker will store their Test in a Session
    private Test myQuiz=null;

    @Override
    public void init(){ 
       String testName = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("QuizName");
       //generate the basic Test which will be used to create each TestTaker's myQuiz
       myQuiz = TestDA.generateTest(testName);


    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
       request.setAttribute("myQuiz", myQuiz);
       //here we are simply showing the test generated from the database
       String action = request.getParameter("action");
       String url = "/QuizView.jsp";
       if(action == null)
       {
           url = "/QuizMain.jsp";
       }
       else if(action.equals("AddTest"))
       {
           url = "/QuizAdd.jsp";
       }
       else if(action.equals("addNewTest"))
       {
           addNewTest(request);
       }



       RequestDispatcher dispatch = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
       dispatch.forward(request, response);

    }

    public boolean addNewTest(HttpServletRequest request)
    {

        return false;
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /** 
    * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
    * @param request servlet request
    * @param response servlet response
    */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } 

    /** 
    * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
    * @param request servlet request
    * @param response servlet response
    */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);

    }

    /** 
    * Returns a short description of the servlet.
    */
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
    // </editor-fold>
}
```

TestDA

```
package org.citatscc.quiz.data;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.citatscc.quiz.business.Question;
import org.citatscc.quiz.business.Test;

public class TestDA{

    public static Test generateTest(String testName) {

        List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();

       Test test = null;
       boolean sameNum = true;
       int randNum1 = 0;
       int randNum2 = 0;
       while(sameNum == true)
       {
           randNum1 = getRandomNumber();
           randNum2 = getRandomNumber();

           if(randNum1 == 0 || randNum2 == 0 || randNum1 > 7 || randNum2 > 7 ||
                   randNum1 == 6 || randNum2 == 6)
           {
               sameNum = true;
           }
           else
           {
                if(randNum1 != randNum2)
                {
                    sameNum = false;
                }
           }

       }

        String questionID1 = getQuestionID(randNum1);
        String questionID2 = getQuestionID(randNum2);
        try {
            String questionTxt1 = getQuestionStringByQID(questionID1);
            String questionTxt2 = getQuestionStringByQID(questionID2);
            questions.add(getAnswers(questionTxt1, questionID1));
            questions.add(getAnswers(questionTxt2, questionID2));
            test = new Test(testName,questions);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String message = ex.getMessage();
        }

        return test;
    }

    public static Question getAnswers(String questionTxt, String questionID) throws Exception
    {
        Connection connection = DBUtil.getConnection();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        int counter = 0;
        int correctAnswer = 0;
        ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
        String preparedQuery = "SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE `qID` = " + questionID;
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(preparedQuery);
        while (resultSet.next())
        {
            answers.add(resultSet.getString(2));
            if(resultSet.getInt(3) == 1)
            {
                correctAnswer = counter;
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        Question question = new Question(questionTxt, answers, correctAnswer);

        return question;
    }

    public static String getQuestionStringByQID(String qID) throws Exception
    {

        Connection connection = DBUtil.getConnection();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        String preparedQuery = "SELECT `question` FROM `questions` WHERE `qID` = " + qID;
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(preparedQuery);
        String questionText = "";
        while (resultSet.next())
        {
            questionText = resultSet.getString(1);
        }
        connection.close();
        return questionText;
    }



    public static int getRandomNumber()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randomNum = rnd.nextInt(8);
        return randomNum;
    }

    public static String getQuestionID(int randNum)
    {
        int intqID = randNum * 111;
        String qID = "" + intqID;

        return qID;
    }

    public static void insertQuestion(String qID, String qText, List<String>qChoices, int correct)throws SQLException{
        String preparedQuestion = "INSERT INTO questions VALUES(?,?)";



    }

    public static void upDateQuestion(String qID, String qText, List<String>qChoices, int correct) throws SQLException{

    }
}
```

after init is finished it redirects to a menu jsp, after a link to take a test is clicked it hits the quizzical controller before being redirected to QuizView.jsp

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
        <title>Quiz View</title>
        <%@taglib  prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

        <%@taglib  prefix="cit"  uri="/WEB-INF/tld/test.tld" %>
        <%@taglib  prefix="includes"  tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/" %>

        <%@ page import="org.citatscc.quiz.business.Test, org.citatscc.quiz.business.Question" %>
        <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
        <link href="quiz.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="top"><includes:Header image="cit_logo.jpg" alt="cit logo image" tagline="${myQuiz.testName}"/></div>
    <div id="leftnav">

    </div>
    <div id="content">

        <form action="Quiz" method="post">
         <c:forEach var="question" items="${myQuiz.questionList}" varStatus="qCount">

             <h2>${qCount.count}.  ${question.questionText} </h2>
             <c:forEach var="choice" items="${question.choices}" varStatus="choiceCount" >
                 <!-- custom tag here -->
                 <cit:quiz_choiceButton groupName="choice${qCount.count}" text="${choice}" value="${choiceCount.index}" />
             </c:forEach>
             <br />
         </c:forEach>
        <input type="submit" name="done" value="Submit" />
        </form> 
    </div>
    <div id="footer"><includes:Footer /></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that this line: `Random rnd = new Random();` Produces a `Random` instance seeded by the current timestamp. If you do it twice in a row very fast, both `Randoms` will have the same seed and thus return the same random numbers. You should instead have one `Random` instance per class and reuse it over and over instead of making new ones.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet method `init()` is called once during servlet initialisation. So, you have the same Test for all your following requests.

```
private Test myQuiz=null;
```

has the same value for all requests.

More in docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#init(javax.servlet.ServletConfig)

Comment: would that cause the same test to be repeated even when the browser is shut down between runs?

Comment: Yes. It will be new test if you shut down your server (or application on the server) and start it again (but not browser). Consider to use session (or request) scope to store your test.